# How to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \cos^n(x)\, dx = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I've got this tasks to prove that:
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \cos^n(x) \,dx = 0$

I tried to think about a partition ${0,t,1}$, and say that if $t$ is small enough, I can get:
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_0^t \cos(x)\, dx = 0$
But then I'm stuck with the rest section $[t,1]$ which approaches $1$.

Any clue?

Comment: How do you feel about integrating complex functions? say, $\int_0^1 e^{i n x} dx$.

Comment: In the course I'm taking now, we don't study complex functions.

Comment: (Note that is it complex-*valued*, but the variable is still real. You can also see it as a function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is you want.)

Answer (score 5):

For any $0<\epsilon< 1$
$$ \int_0^1\cos^n xdx=\int_0^{\frac\epsilon2}\cos^nxdx+\int^1_{\frac\epsilon2}\cos^nxdx\le\frac\epsilon2+\cos^n(\frac\epsilon2)<\frac\epsilon2+\frac\epsilon2=\epsilon\text{ as }n\text{ large}. $$

Comment: Ok, but  I can't let $\delta$ be zero, so how can I proceed from here?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Thanks! You meant $\cos^n(\frac\epsilon2)$  instead of $cos^n(\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: @EitanKosman, yes. It is a typo.